# Mockking return value of imported class

Tags: kotlin, mocking, mockk

preemptive excuse for bad explenation.

But I am attempting to test the functionality of a logic statement within my class:

```
import ClassIWantToMockk

class MyClass {

fun myMethodToTest(string: String): Boolean = string == ClassIWantToMockk.methodReturningObject.toString()

}
```

I want to control the returned string from the method in the imported class in my test class. The class contains an override of the toString() method if that is relevant.

I just cant seem to find out how I can control the return without an instance of the class as a parameter...

best regards

Comment: do you want to control return value of a "static" (companion object's to be precise) method/property of a class?

Comment: share the code that you want to test